# react-table not updating rows when removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, chakra-ui, react-table-v7

i'm using react-table v7.8.0, and i have a cell which removes a item from a cart (react context),
when i remove one item, the table removes a item, but then do not remove any more items, i have to refresh the page, so start function again.

i'm using nextjs, chakra-ui, and react-table,
the props come from a parent component,

any help?
below there is my component:

```js
interface TabelaCarrinhoProps {
  units: Unit[];
  workspaces: Workspace[];
  reservations: Reservation[],
  removeReservation: (reservation: Reservation) => void
}

export function TabelaCarrinho({units, workspaces, reservations, removeReservation}: TabelaCarrinhoProps) {
  const [rowsData, setRows] = useState(reservations)

  useEffect(() => {
    setRows([...reservations])
  }, [reservations])

  const data = useMemo(() => rowsData, [rowsData])

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Data',
        accessor: 'reservation_date',
        Cell:({cell: {value}}: any) => <>{moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Periodo',
        accessor: 'period',
        Cell: ({cell: {value}}: Period) =>
          <>
            {`${value.beginHour} - ${value.endHour}`}
          </>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Unidade',
        accessor: 'period.unitId',
        Cell: ({cell: {value}}) =>
          <>
            {units.find(el => el.id === value).name}
          </>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Estação',
        accessor: 'workspace_id',
        Cell: ({cell: {value}}) =>
          <>
            <Text>
              {workspaces.find(el => el.id === value).name}
            </Text>

          </>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Preço',
        accessor: 'period.price',
        Cell:({cell: {value}}: any) =>
          <>
            {new Intl.
            NumberFormat('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency:'BRL'}).format(value)}
          </>
      },
      {
        Header: '',
        accessor: 'id',
        Cell:({cell}: any) =>
          <>
            <Button size={"sm"}
                    colorScheme={"red"}
                    onClick={e => {
                      removeReservation(cell.row.original)
                    }}
            >Remover</Button>
          </>
      }
    ], []
  )


  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    // @ts-ignore
  } = useTable({columns, data}, useSortBy, useExpanded)
  return (

  // ... table comes here
}
```

Edit 1:
as asked, below the code from removeReservations:

```
const removeReservation = (reservation: Reservation) => {
try {
  const updatedCart = new Set(cart);
  updatedCart.delete(reservation)

  if (updatedCart.size <= cart.length) {
  setCart(Array.from(updatedCart))
  } else {
    throw Error('Erro ao remover produto do carrinho')
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

}

Comment: in this case, you should show us the process inside your `removeReservation`

Comment: remove reservation is inside a React.Context, i edit the question with the respective code